# Database design for patients and diseases

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating an application (desktop) to store and retrieve patients' records along with diseases. As patients and diseases have a many to many relationship, so I've created three tables; PATIENTS, DISEASES and one is Junction table. As one patient can register more than once in a single disease over the time so 'PATIENTS' table contains composite primary key of patient's 'reference no' and 'registration date'. Table 'DISEASES' only contains 'name' as a primary key.

Now I am a little confused about the design of junction table. It is containing the composite primary key of 'PATIENTS' table and a primary key of 'DISEASES' table as foreign keys.

Should I make composite primary key of all these foreign keys in junction table or create another primary key or something different?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've also wrote sql queries for the database and I can provide if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you one more table for cases. This table would contain an entry date. You should not use the disease name as primary key. This would make it difficult to correct typos or simply to choose a more appropriate name in the future, or maybe you would want to have a Latin as well as an English name.

```
Patient table
-------------
PK  PatientID
    Name
    DateOfBirth
    etc.
```

```
Disease table
-------------
PK  DiseaseID
    Name
```

```
Case table
-------------
PK  CaseID
FK  PatientID
    EntryDate
    etc.
```

```
CaseDisease table
-------------
PK, FK  CaseID
PK, FK  DiseaseID
```

Now you have these relations

```
Patient --1:n--> Case --1:n--> CaseDisease <--n:1-- Disease
```

---

EDIT:

The case table might not be necessary for now and might seem to be over-designed. However, should it turn out in future, that you have to store other data to a case as well; the db design would not have to be changed fundamentally.

---

UPDATE:

Alternatively, you could do it without a case table. In that case, the junction table would have a date as part of the primary key

```
PatientDisease table
-------------
PK, FK  PatientID
PK, FK  DiseaseID
PK      Date
```

The relations would be

```
Patient --1:n-->  PatientDisease <--n:1-- Disease
```

Comment: Why have you added the `Case` table? The OP hasn't indicated that there's a need for that.

Comment: It is just a suggestion. There is nothing wrong with it. I added a suggestion without a case table.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem like that design is quite right. If the patient's reference number uniquely identifies the *patient*, then *that* should be the primary key. If the same patient can register for a given disease multiple times, then that should be part of the key in the junction table, not in the patient table.

The primary key in the junction table should be what uniquely identifies an association, which in this case should be a composite key composed of the key from the patient table, the disease table, and the registration date.

Answer (score 1):

1. 'name' as a primary key is not a good idea - there shoud be an Id column in that table which should be set as primary key
2. DiseasesToPatients table should be made of both foreign keys - from Patients and Diseases tables and they should be set as composite primary key on that table.

Comment: Name is as good of a primary key as any other candidate key if it's stable. Adding a surrogate key for no reason is needless.

Comment: What about performance of nvarchar and int column comparision?

Comment: The OP does not indicate what the type of his column is. Even so, a properly indexed table would make the difference almost negligible.

Comment: In my case, if name is no longer a primary key of diseases table then it should have a constraint of uniqueness and I think the diseases table for some clinic would not have a large no of diseases. So maybe it is better not to add another column.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - In some cultures it is acceptable to change names when changing marital status, gender, entering a convent, ... .  Makes for an unstable primary key.

Comment: @user92546: I wasn't aware that diseases got married. To your point in a general case, though, I said that it makes a perfectly reasonable candidate key **if it's stable**. If it's subject to change, it is (by definition) unstable and thus not suited to be a key.